# declarating variable in loop will cost more performance?

Tags: c++, for-loop, memory, memory-management, while-loop

code 1

```
while(1)
{
    int i = 0;
    //do something
}
```

code 2

```
int i = 0;
while(1)
{
    i = 0;
    //do something
}
```

Is the performance of these two codes the same or is code 1 more expensive?

=========================================================================

very impressive output
here is my test code

```
class A {};

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 10000;
    clock_t check;

    check = clock();
    while(count < maxCount)
    {
    int i = 0;
    count++;
    }
    cout << clock() - check << endl;

    count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    check = clock();
    while(count < maxCount)
    {
    i = 0;
    count++;
    }
    cout << clock() - check << endl;

    check = clock();
    while(count < maxCount)
    {
    A a;
    count++;
    }
    cout << clock() - check << endl;

    check = clock();
    while(count < maxCount)
    {
    A* a = new A();
    count++;
    delete a;
    }
    cout << clock() - check << endl;
}
```

and the every output is 0.

i think compiler's optimization is very powerful. thank you for you guys and if my test code is wrong, give me some advise!

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking this yourself?

Comment: Measure. but for `int` I doubt there is any difference, and that is the bottleneck of your program.

Comment: @UnholySheep ah! with clock() function in <time.h> header? thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, when compiling with optimisation, I wouldn't expect the emitted code to be any different.   Ways to check - and be sure - is to either examine the code (e.g. assembler) output by the compiler, and to systematically benchmark/measure performance.   Practically, I'd use the first, unless code AFTER the loop requires usage of `i`  i.e.   performance is not the consideration.    Unless I have benchmarking demonstrating a performance concern for the program as a whole, I wouldn't bother benchmarking to test if this case matters.

Comment: Check out Scott Meyer's Effective C++. He goes over this exact scenario and advocates for 'code 2' as the general rule.

Comment: @john.dennis Which adds weight to the maxim that nobody's perfect. Including Scott Meyers.

Comment: @john.dennis which item is it? I am curious if the example is really about an `int`. I would understand if he suggests to keep expensive construction out of the loop but an `int` ?!?

Comment: @john.dennis The specific case where Scott suggests this is for the variable being of a class type, with an expensive constructor or destructor, and inexpensive reassignment. In the first case, there would be one construction and one destruction for every loop iteration. In the second, a single construction and destruction, plus one assignment per iteration. That analysis isn't applicable for basic types like `int`, and compilers can probably do a better job of optimising the code that a programmer can.  His conclusion, BTW, is to delay variable definitions "as long as possible" i.e. "code 1".

Comment: @Peter you're right that's what I wanted to reference. "code 1" keeps it in the loop. I misread the OP.

Comment: Your benchmark is indeed not relevant, most loops might be replaced by `count = std::max(maxCount, count);`. inner loop is no-op. In C++14, `delete new A;` might be elided. And anyway `A` does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, with compiler *optimisations* turned on, if you can think of a way of speeding up some code by making a small change such as the one you make, then so can the very clever authors of such compilers.

Certainly keeping variables as local as possible helps optimisation strategies. And it's better programming style.

You can always check the generated assembly if you are in any doubt that the compiler has done its job well.

Comment: what is exactly mean of keep variables as local as possible? is it means that code 1 style? which life time is under while loop?

Comment: @신승빈  - "as local as possible", in the context as possible, means "in the smallest possible scope".   "code 1" puts the variable `i` in a smaller scope than "code 2".

Comment: @Peter thanks! the performance of both are equal because the compiler optimize the code, so keep variables life cycle as local as possible! right?

Comment: @신승빈: Exactly! In the "Code2" you splash `i` about all over the surrounding scope. It's untidy: rather like a teenager's bedroom.